# MS Graph get copied driveItem with AsyncMonitor

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I need to get a driveItem after Copy request to MS Graph. As I understood I need to handle request header `Location` to get url for monitoring a copy procedure according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/long-running-actions-overview?tabs=http).
Also I'm using an `AsyncMonitor<DriveItem>` with Task `PollForOperationCompletionAsync`.

But by the end of copying I'm receiving an error with `authorization error: Invalid Audience`

I guess I'm receiving this error because asyncMonitor redirects me to `resourceUrl`  after succesfull copy, which is a SharePoint REST API endpoint: `https://{tenant-name}.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/{driveItem}`

If my approach is correct then please explain me why I'm receiving resource from **SharePoint REST API** while using **MS Graph API**. Bacause of that I need exchange tokens, etc

My code:

```
    var copyResponse = await client.Sites[siteId].Lists[listId].Drive.Items[file.DriveItemId]
            .Copy(file.Name, reference)
            .Request()
            .PostResponseAsync();

    var locationHeader = copyResponse.HttpHeaders.Location;
    if (locationHeader == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    if (!locationHeader.IsAbsoluteUri)
    {
        locationHeader = new Uri(client.BaseUrl + locationHeader.OriginalString);
    }

    IProgress<AsyncOperationStatus> progress = new Progress<AsyncOperationStatus>(operationStatus =>
    {
        logger.LogInformation(
            $"Copying file {file.Name} status: {operationStatus.Status}");
    });

    var asyncMonitor = new AsyncMonitor<DriveItem>(client, locationHeader.AbsoluteUri);
    var result =  await asyncMonitor.PollForOperationCompletionAsync(progress, CancellationToken.None);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new GraphServiceClient without auth header worked for me:

```
var monitorClient = new GraphServiceClient(
    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (d) => { await Task.CompletedTask; }));
var monitor = new AsyncMonitor<CopyAsyncOperationStatus>(monitorClient, locationHeader.AbsoluteUri);
```

Where `CopyAsyncOperationStatus` is something like this:

```
internal class CopyAsyncOperationStatus: AsyncOperationStatus
{
    [JsonPropertyName("resourceId")]
    public string ResourceId { get; set; }
        
    [JsonPropertyName("statusDescription")]
    public string StatusDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Then I use check the status in the result and use ResourceId to get information about the new file.

```
if(status.Status != "completed" || status.ResourceId == null)
{
    throw new Exception($"Error ...");
}

var fileId = status.ResourceId;
```

Comment: Similar way I used in my code, and it's working. But I still don't get it why do the trying to redirect me to sharepoint rest api